# Rails Omniauth - NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I am following the tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?autoplay=true

I have my own sign-in and out process working. But when I try to authenticate twitter login I have

**NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create**

```
undefined method `authentications' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

My routes is:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'authentications#create'
```

In my authentication controller, create method is:

```
def create
    auth =  request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth[:provider], :uid => auth[:uid])
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
```

I don't know what is the problem :/

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. Since I'm not logged in to the system, current_user is null, therefore it gaves an error.

+

now I wrote all of my experiences and made a tutorial with the source code, that provides multiple authentication with Facebook and Twitter: 
http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/